# Javascript querystring to object conversion

Tags: javascript, optimization, array

The below code converts the window.location.search querystring into a JavaScript object. In particular, if a key occurs more than once the resulting value in the object will be an array. Please feel free to comment on both readability and speed of execution. Thanks!

```
window.location.search.split(/[?&]/g).reduce(function (prev, cur, idx, arr) {
    var segment = cur.split("="),
        key = segment[0],
        val = segment[1];
    if (prev[key]) {
        if (prev[key] instanceof Array) {
            prev[key].push(val);
        } else {
            prev[key] = [prev[key], val];
        }
    } else {
        prev[key] = val;
    }
    return prev;
}, { });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `if (typeof prev[key] === typeof []) {` is... weird. If you're checking for a type specifically, check for it: `if (typeof prev[key] === 'object') {` - the way you're doing it there causes a new array literal to be instantiated needlessly, as well as a superfluous `typeof` operation, both inefficient and outright unnecessary.

Making an array out of repeating keys is fallacious - if a key is exactly repeated in a query string, only the right-most instance of that query string value will be received by the server. Further, in cases where the query string contains validly structured arrays (`test=1&test2[]=2&test2[]=4`), your code ends up with a key like `test[]`, which is a nasty to access: `results['test2[]']` is the only way to get at it (no dot syntax allowed).

---

**EDIT**
To clarify my remarks about duplicating keys, I purhaps mistakenly restricted my comments to Apache(Linux or Windows)/PHP - certainly other languages and platforms are relevant to the discussion. In the PHP language (what I am most familiar with), the query string `test=1&test=2` will result in:

```
var_export($_GET);
/* array (
  'test' => '2',
) */
```

... as you can see, only the right-most value is the only one passed into the script. The way PHP expects duplicate query string keys is by use of `[]` in the query: `test[]=1&test[]=2`

```
var_export($_GET);
/*array (
  'test' => 
      array (
        0 => '1',
        1 => '2',
  ),
)*/
```

This behavior is the same for POST data on PHP - you must use `name="myField[]"` if multiple fields will use the same name, otherwise, only the last item in the form with a given name will be populated in PHP's `$_POST` data.

I am not set up to confirm the behavior of this in ASP (or other languages), however research has indicated that my assertion is still somewhat valid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395290/how-may-i-add-integer-list-to-route/6396793#6396793. Please confirm if you are able: from what I have gathered the values would be passed to script as a comma-delimited list, but the language itself still rejects working with duplicate keys and a workaround is required.

If you can add some data about handling of duplicate keys in other server languages, please feel free to edit them into this answer. That said, I feel my criticism of this script's handling of duplicate keys stands, as well as the issue with "properly formed" (PHP) arrays in the query string - `result['test[]']` is nasty.

Comment: Right. Not only is it weird, it's wrong. I based that line on a SO answer without testing it properly. What I needed was `prev[key] instanceof Array`. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Please see edit, still looking and adding :)

Comment: Your answer is appreciated, but I think you're wrong about the arrays. Otherwise, how would HTML forms be able to pass the multiple values of several checkboxes with the same name? Indeed, a quick test shows that an array is exactly how application servers in Coldfusion and PHP see repeated keys in query strings.

Comment: The server will receive all values in the query string. If some server implementation chooses to discard values then that is specific to that implementation. IIS (Windows) doesn't discard any values, for example.

Comment: Please see my edit regarding this issue, and indeed, please post your IIS results into the answer if you'd like!

Comment: The discarding of values appears to be language-specific rather than platform-specific, but the utility of the OP's code is certainly limited if it does not address considerations relevant at least to the most widespread languages (PHP being one). The lack of standardization for URIs makes this more complex, purhaps, than it seems on the surface

Comment: This turned out to be a fascinating and informative exchange, but to clarify, my question really is only focused on JavaScript. For the purposes of the above review I'm not concerned about the conventions of other languages, regardless of their popularity. That said, of course, review as you see fit.

Comment: Of course... my thinking was only that the utility of a query string parser is somewhat dependent upon the validity of the parsed data - if you aren't able to immediately post the query string back to the server as-is and have the server-side language use the query string exactly as javascript would use it, then it invites the possibility of inconsistencies in operation client-side, thus potential errors.

Comment: PHP uses a non-standard approach with query strings. `?foo=bar&foo=baz` should contain both values as far as the uri specification is concerned `foo=["bar","baz"]` should be the expected result, but PHP uses a non-standard approach that would lead to `foo="baz"`.

Comment: Non-standard? There isn't a standard that I have ever seen that dictates how languages should handle URIs. Can you provide a link to this "standard"? As far as URI standardization goes, this is all you get: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt - nothing in there describing duplicate keys in query parameters.

Comment: @Chris as far as I can tell, there is no standard that explicitly states how a language should parse a querystring. That said, does PHP really require you to put '[]' at the end of the names of all HTML controls that *might* result in an array in the form data set? That seems like extra work, at best. At worst, silently throwing away data is likely to prove harmful.

Comment: Yes, it does require the `[]` on a form element if you want the array in post data. As for the behavior, I am undecided on what I prefer; having only worked with PHP in this regard it seems perfectly natural, but I can certainly see the downfalls too.

Answer (score 1):

`.reduce()` is not supported for IE version < 9. If anyone uses this in their application, make sure that this is not an issue. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/reduce#Browser_compatibility) is a potential workaround.

Comment: Yep, I was aware of this, but should've pointed it out for future readers. Thanks!